# Taking to long time to run .SQL Script in AZURE using sql server management studio and C# coding

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database

I have face a problem to Create Database and run the .SQL Script file in Azure  using C#.
When i test it manually in my Local machine and local machine instance it takes only **15 Sec** , but when i run this same script file in Azure it takes **6 mints and 37 sec** . i have no idea why it is taking such a long time. can you please help me...

I Generate the script like below using SQL server Management Studio(version :11.0.9230 )

1. Script for the database Engine Type : **SQL Azure Database**
2. Types of data to script  :  **Schema and data**
3. Script Triggers: **True**

   **Total Size of Script file : 6553 KB.**

When run the same script file through Coding it takes almost 12 mints and 48 sec . 
C# Code :

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^GO", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
                        string SQLAllText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "SQLEXPRESS\\Emptyscript.sql");
                        string[] SqlLine = regex.Split(SQLAllText);
                        foreach (string Line in SqlLine)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Errormessage = Line;
                                SqlCmd.CommandText = Line;
                                SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {

                                MessageBox.Show(Errormessage);
                                objLog.Write(ex, "NewCompanyDatabaseWCF", "CreateDatabase");
                            }
                        }
```

Can you please Guide me how can i run the Script file very Quickly in Azure

Thanks

Victor.A

Comment: Could you post parts of the scipt so we can see what you are doing?

Comment: Hi Luc, thanks for you reply , parts of the script means can i post fullscript file or can i post on few of script lines...? i have lot of files (SP,Triggers and views).

Comment: Usually creating tables views en triggers is fast. What can be slow is 1 of the following actions:
-Insert many records
-Create indexes on large tables
-Updating data

Comment: in my case , i added a new line for Creating (CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX LoginDetail_Index ) for only Two tables  and i have insert few tables data..

Comment: Are you on basic, standard, or premium?

Comment: Hi @ Joseph Idziorek, if you are talking abount Azure account ,  i have  premium  account .

Answer (score 3):

The execution speed of the script depends on the performance tier your database is in and how much resource your queries are buring. You can query "sys.resource_Stats" view to see the resource usage while executing the script. If you want this script to execute fast and one time then scale up your database, execute the script, and scale down. You can also use the other dmvs like dm_exec_Requests, dm_db_Wait_stats to see the bottlenecks.